# How to change the default xcode version that is launched...?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have both xcode 3.2 and 4.0 version installed on my PC but my problem is whenever I open a project, it opens up with xcode 3.2. Although I have the option of opening my project with open with->xcode 4.0 , I want to change the default Xcode to 4.0. Is there any way it can be done?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/25913478/1835803

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use Finder's context menu (i.e. right click on the project) and choose "Get Info"

In the window that pops up is a section titled "Open With" - use that to choose the appropriate version of Xcode, and then use the "Change All" button to specify that it should be used for all projects.

On my machine I renamed `Xcode.app` for Xcode 3 to `Xcode 3` which makes it easy to distinguish between the two versions.

Answer (score 5):

First right click on the Project whichever you want to open.
Now select the openWith option and choose "Other" option.

Now choose the Xcode 4.0 that is installed on your MAC.
Select All Application from Enable Menu and also check "Always Open With Option".
Then Click OK.