# How to set Xcode version as default in my Mac?

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode-command-line-tools

Right now I have Xcode 6.0 (Beta) as a default version of my Xcode, but today I installed Xcode 6 from App Store and so I want to set Xcode 6 as
a default version.

How can I set it?

Comment: Just delete the beta because why would you need to keep it now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the default xcode version that is launched...?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532074/how-to-change-the-default-xcode-version-that-is-launched)

Answer (score 203):

You could set the desired Xcode using this in the terminal:

```
sudo xcode-select -s <path/to/>Xcode.app
```

also, for more info, [click here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2339/_index.html)

Comment: It should be --s. sudo xcode-select --switch

Answer (score 63):

Not directly related, however I assume most of you'd find this useful. [Here is a link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2339/_index.html) showing the command line FAQs.

The most 2 useful commands are.

1. Printing the version of Xcode currently used by my tools

> xcode-select --print-path

2. Select the default Xcode for your command-line tools

> sudo xcode-select -switch Xcode.app
>
> E.g: `sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode5.1.1/Xcode.app`

Comment: This answer was outdated!

Answer (score 51):

It should be easy.

**Solution 1:**

- Right click(or <kbd>Control</kbd> + Click) on Xcode project file (*.xcodeproj*).
- Hover over 'Open with' and you will find all the Xcode apps from Applications directory listed.

[image: Screen Shot of multiple Xcode apps]

- Now, hold down the <kbd>Option</kbd> key so that the “Open With” menu becomes “Always Open With”.
- Continue to hold <kbd>Option</kbd> and select the Xcode version you want to set as the default for this file.

**Solution 2**:

Another way to apply this change to all the similar files is by clicking "Get info" and then making necessary change in 'Open With' section.

[image]

Comment: Solution 2 is the one I was looking for.

Comment: Terminal based answers didn't work for me to change from Xcode-10-beta to Xcode-9.4, **Solution 2 did the trick**, thanks!

Answer (score 25):

In 10.10 you should use (Assuming you've installed few versions of Xcode  as Xcode6.1, Xcode6.2 and Xcode6.3, and want to make Xcode6.3 as default one).

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode6.3.app
```

This comes handy with some 3rd party applications which fails to reset the path from OSX like SVNX.app

Answer (score 5):

This works for me I'm using vanilla titanium CLI.

Switch to desired Xcode version followed by `ti setup` for `ios`

> sudo xcode-select -switch /path/to/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/
>
> ti setup ios

Answer (score 3):

If you do a lot of work in both the current and beta version of Xcode run `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app` to select the default xcode and rename the beta Xcode to `XcodeBeta.app` or `Xcode10.app`.

Whenever you want to upgrade just rename the Xcode and restart terminal.