# Cocoapods - Module Compiled with Swift 3.0 cannot be imported in Swift 3.0.1

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, version

Just updated to Xcode v8.1 and am trying to install a pod. However, once I import it, Xcode gives me an error saying `Module Compiled with Swift 3.0 cannot be imported in Swift 3.0.1` and then a path to the module.

I have tried saying `Use Legacy Swift Language Version` however this does not solve the issue.

Any other ideas of what I can change to make this compile? I have a hard time believing a minor version change should cause this much trouble.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: **legacy swift language version**  set YES if not working then try  **carthage update --platform iOS --no-use-binaries**

Comment: Which pod are you trying to install?

Answer (score 0):

This happens almost every update. Try `pod update` in the terminal where the pods are located to get all your pods to the latest versions.

Comment: Yes. This is a new pod I am adding to the project so it is up to date.

Comment: @PhilipSawyer try referencing this question, and see if that works. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40250381/module-compiled-with-swift-3-0-cannot-be-imported-in-swift-3-0-1

Answer (score 0):

Just clean your project.

Select: **Product -> Clean**