# Module compiled with Swift 3.0.1 cannot be imported in Swift 3.0 on BuddyBuild

Tags: swift, xcode, realm, carthage

I use **BuddyBuild** for a swift project with **Xcode 8.0** and with Carthage 0.18. 
Although, in logs I can see that all frameworks are cloning, checking out and building, I receive this one:

> module compiled with Swift 3.0.1 cannot be imported in Swift 3.0: /tmp/sandbox/workspace/Carthage/Build/iOS/RealmSwift.framework/Modules/RealmSwift.swiftmodule/x86_64.swiftmodule

This is the entry in Cartfile for Realm:

> github "realm/realm-cocoa"

**Locally**, everything builds, but with other configurations:
Xcode 8.1 and Carthage 0.18

This [Module compiled with swift 3.0 cannot be imported in Swift 3.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40250381/module-compiled-with-swift-3-0-cannot-be-imported-in-swift-3-0-1) did not help me much, because of BuddyBuild.

**EDIT**
I can see that in logs:

> Downloading realm-cocoa.framework binary at "v2.1.0"

after that, no building for realm.

Comment: Do you use this framework in your framework/library or in your application?

Comment: application - In a Xcode project that uses Carthage to include frameworks

Answer (score 0):

Buddybuild typically run the carthage command with `--no-build` to make sure you don't experience with kind of error.

Note that buddybuild won't run the `carthage` command if you check in your `Carthage/` folder.

You can find more information about [how buddybuild deals with Carthage](https://docs.buddybuild.com/builds/dependencies/carthage.html) in our documentation.