# Alamofire module not compiling with Swift 3.0.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire

I have an Xcode project in Swift 3.0.1, and am getting this error upon trying to build:

`Module compiled with Swift 3.0 cannot be imported in Swift 3.0.1: <path_to_project>/Alamofire.framework/Modules/Alamofire.swiftmodule/x86_64.swiftmodule`

I've referenced this question: [Module compiled with swift 3.0 cannot be imported in Swift 3.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40250381/module-compiled-with-swift-3-0-cannot-be-imported-in-swift-3-0-1), but the selected answer did not work.

The contents of my Cartfile is simply:
`github "Alamofire/Alamofire"`

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your root folder like what you did with '.gitignore'

> .swift-version

'.swift-version' should contain '3.0-GM-CANDIDATE' then do 'pod install'

Comment: I'm not using CocoaPods, just Carthage. However, adding the file and doing  `carthage update --platform iOS --no-use-binaries` did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You may have multiple Xcode.

check your xcode path

```
xcode-select --print-path
```

check your swift version

```
xcrun swift --version
```

carthage will build based on the swift version that printed in terminal by above command.

**Solution**

```
sudo xcode-select --switch <your new Xcode path>

carthage update --no-use-binaries --platform iOS
```