# Swift 3.0.1 support of SwiftyJSON framework

Tags: swifty-json

Does [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) support Swift version 3.0.1?
The swift-version file states the version 3.0.
Need to know whether it supports swift 3.0.1 or not.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because it has to be compiled with Xcode 8.1, if you use carthage you do `carthage update --platform <yourPlatform> --no-use-binaries`

For more information look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40339551/2448287)