# Unable to use an added framework in Xcode 8.3

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks

I get this error:

> /Users/gb/Documents/dev/ya-ios-sdk-demo-simple/ya-ios-sdk-demo-simple/ViewController.swift:10:8: Module compiled with Swift 3.0.2 cannot be imported in Swift 3.1:
>   /Users/gb/Documents/dev/ya-ios-sdk-demo-simple/YA.framework/Modules/YA.swiftmodule/arm64.swiftmodule

Before upgrading my Xcode, everything was running OK.

Comment: check this link may helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40250381/module-compiled-with-swift-3-0-cannot-be-imported-in-swift-3-0-1

Comment: Are you using Carthage?